# Automatically add core fields to a table when created

Tags: mysql, trigger, timestamp

I was reading these articles on StackOverflow regarding triggers and created date and updated date in mysql, and was wondering whether it is possible to create a trigger that checks if these two fields are present in the create table statement, and either creates the relevant trigger, or creates the fields, as well as the trigger? I am aware that there will be some tables for which this is not relevant, but I will address that in the future.

[What is the best way to set up last-modified and date-record-added fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295472/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-up-last-modified-and-date-record-added-fields)

[adding column to all tables in a mysql database (unknown table names)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706740/adding-column-to-all-tables-in-a-mysql-database-unknown-table-names)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are asking for is called "DDL triggers".

And no, MySQL doesn't have that. So you can't do this in a trigger.

Comment: So I will have to make sure to add the triggers manually. Thank you. Do you know if mariadb or postgresql have the feature?

Comment: Postgres has [Event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-definition.html) - implemented in 9.3 - but I've never used that feature.

Comment: @JoSSte , also - each tasks have many ways for realisation, main question - what the goals? Why You need create this? As example - MariaDB  have excellent Audit Plugin (compatible with any MySQL) - it allow You audit all DDL changes, You can parse them and use this information.